nfcpy is not recognising reader
I have an acs acr1222l-d1 rfid reader connected via USB.  When I run NFC Tools I can see the device and it recognises when an rfid tag is brought near.
Using spyder IDE, I tried some simple code to read the UID
from nfc import ContactlessFrontend
from time import sleep

def get_uid(tag):
  """
  This function extracts the UID from the tag object and formats it.
  """
  uid = ''.join('{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in tag.identifier)
  return uid

def main():
  """
  This function continuously reads tags and prints their UID.
  """
  clf = ContactlessFrontend('usb')
  print("Waiting for NFC tag...")
  while True:
    clf.connect(rdwr={'on-connect': lambda tag: print(get_uid(tag))})
    sleep(1)  # Debounce for repeated tag detection

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main() 

All I need is the UID but instead I get:
  File d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File d:\mcmah\google drive\learning\lit\dissertation\spo2\nfc2.py:17
    clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')

  File d:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nfc\clf\__init__.py:76 in __init__
    raise IOError(errno.ENODEV, os.strerror(errno.ENODEV))

OSError: [Errno 19] No such device

It's the only device connected, so at a loss.  Any ideas why nfcpy won't see the reader?
